# Killing singleton object

Tags: java, android

In my current android application I have created one Singleton Object which is responsible to communicate with Secure Element and also storing some secrets in file in internal storage.

Now scenario is like if user wants to change the Secure Element He can just unplugged it and insert it again and when he do that he is asked to clear data from application.

As my current application's process(even though I have closed my all activities) is not killed yet my Singleton Object is not get cleared.

But I want to reset the state of my Singleton Object or say I want to create new Singleton Object and delete previous one.

Below is my implementation:

```
public class SEManager {
    private static SEManager INSTANCE = null;

    private SEManager() {
    }

    public static void init() throws Exception {
        if (INSTANCE != null) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid Operation");
        }
        INSTANCE = new SEManager();
    }

    public static SEManager getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

I am confuse how to reset object state or delete its reference.
One solution coming in mind is

```
public static synchronized void reset(){
    INSTANCE = null;
}
```

But I am not able to figure out its disadvantage.

Comment: Why don't you use an `enum`? There are no real singletons though since in  clustered system there will be one instance of this class in every  separate JVM.

Comment: init() doesn't need to be public.. Why not make it private and call it from getInstance()?. Why throw an exception if you try to reinitialize an object (why not return the same object?)

Comment: Singletons are designed to have the same lifespan as the application, so if you have a use case where you need to destroy the Singleton, then maybe you've made a wrong design decision.

Comment: I can only reiterate Egor's statement. If your Singleton needs to be destroyed to change its state then you are doing it wrong!

Comment: @Egor Even only lazily initialized singletons contradict your statement, sorry.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would just init the singleton instance on creation and not lazily - then, when resetting, you can simple replace `INSTANCE` with a new object.

```
public static synchronized void reset(){
    INSTANCE = new SEManager();
}
```

Comment: Does making it null will create any issue in multi threaded envirinment?

Comment: I can't imagine right now, but as your object is not heavyweight (as long as you don't allocate DB access?), I don't see any advantage in lazy loading.

Comment: It creates issues if you forget to use the `synchronized` keyword on the `init` and `reset` functions.

Comment: isn't it better to use a specific object for monitor?

Comment: @Zhuinden The `synchronized` keyword for a method is a short cut for `synchonized(this) { ... }` spanning the whole method body.